# Clion scanf duplicating previous line

Tags: c, mingw, clion

I'm new to C and I'm following through some tutorials, but I keep getting an error when running code in CLion.

Whenever I use `scanf` it always seems to duplicate the previous line in the console.

Here's what it's outputting:

```
Please enter your first number:5
Please enter your first number: 5
Please enter your second number:6
Please enter your second number: 6
5 < 6
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here's what I think it should output:

```
Please enter your first number:5
Please enter your second number:6
5 < 6
Process finished with exit code 0
```

And of course, here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int no1;
    int no2;

    printf("Please enter your first number: ");
    scanf(" %d", &no1);

    printf("Please enter your second number: ");
    scanf(" %d", &no2);

    if(no1 < no2){
        printf("%d < %d", no1, no2);
    } else if (no1 == no2) {
        printf("Both numbers are %d", no1);
    } else {
        printf("%d > %d", no1, no2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm also using MinGW 3.21, CMake 3.5.1

**Edit:**
I just ran the code on the normal command line and found this isn't a problem there. It appears to just be CLion's console.

Comment: Strange indeed. It does behave correctly on my Mac. Sidenote: the format for `scanf` should just be `"%d"` (though the behaviour is the same on my system with both formats). Also, you're missing the `\n` in your final `printf`'s.

Comment: @da Yeah, the space didn't end up making a difference. I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: @DarkDust: The leading space eats up whitespace. Not necessary for the first input, but it might be relevant for the second. It should be kept.

Comment: `scanf` does not output anything, so it is either your terminal or your standard library. Add `fflush(stdout);` between `printf` and `scanf`.

Comment: @olaf That didn't seem to fix the problem, I've added more info to the question though.

Comment: The code also works with Ubuntu without duplicates

Comment: @Olaf the space is redundant in both cases because `%d` consumes leading whitespace

Answer (score 1):

It a bug in CLion's console - [CPP-2580](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2580)
There are two possible workarounds:

1. Turn off PTY: by disabling run.processes.with.pty option in the Registry (Help -> Find Action -> Registry...)
2. Use Cygwin instead of MinGW